# Find points of tangency for a given function.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, tangent-line

I have spent 3 hours or so trying to tackle this problem but the answers I get arent the ones written on the page , I do not want to assume that the asnwers on the page are incorrect so here I go ,

*The Problem*

The graph :

$y=\frac{5x}{4} + \frac{1}{x}$

(In the first quarter) , has a tangent in point A , and a tangent in point B (both tangent to the function graph) that are perpendicular to each other . (90 deagrees).
It is given that the rate of x of point A is bigger by times 3 than point B (Xa = $t$ while Xb = $\frac{1}{3}t$).

1. Find the credentials (x , y) of point A , and point B if it is given that the X of point A , is a natural number (bigger than zero , and not a fraction).
2. (Didnt finish 1. so didnt get to it)

**What I did :**

I wrote that the x of point a is t , then I found the derivative of 
$f{(t)}$ which is equal to the angle of tangence (or in other words $m$ of $t$) , derivative : $f'{(t)} = 1.25 + -\frac{1}{t^2}$

after that I found the derivative of point B $(\frac{1}{3}t , f{(\frac{1}{3}t)})$ Which was $f'(\frac{1}{3}t) =  \frac{5}{12} + 3 == 3.416$

I was taught that $m1 * m2 = -1$ . so I took the two m's and followed through :

Ma = $1.25 + -\frac{1}{t^2}$ , Mb = $3.416$ .

Then Ma * Mb == -1 (Right ?)

$(1.25 + -\frac{1}{t^2}) * 3.416 =  -1$
Which led me to $5.27t^2 = 3.416$ led me to this --> $t = 0.7726$

**The answers in the book show :** A(2,3) and B(0.666 , 2.666) ,

I tried finding my mistake  , but it seems that this also leads me to this. what did I miss here?

Would love some help and insight , The problem was translated , took me a while , hope you understand it (my English isn't perfect to say the least).

Comment: If the rate at A is three times the rate at B this becomes $f'(a)=3f'(b)$ for the $x$ coordinates of A,B. On the other hand since the tangent lines are perpendicular one has $f'(a) \cdot f'(b)=-1.$ So it seems a peculiar setup.

Comment: I didn't mean rate , It's just the litteral translation from hebrew , it says in the book , that the x of A is bigger than the x of B X3. if it also translates to rate , then I apologies truely for being stupid and answering this. lol

Comment: So in my comment it is $a=3b$ right?

Answer (score 1):

The statement $f′(\frac{t}{3})=5/12+3 = 3.416$ is not true. $f′(\frac{t}{3}) = 1.25 - \frac{9}{t^2}$. At $B(2/3,8/3)$, $t=2$, which gives $f′(\frac{2}{3}) = -1$ and $f(\frac{2}{3})=\frac{7}{3}$ (I think there is an error in text book, since it says $\frac{8}{3}$ instead).

At $A(2,3)$: $\;t=6$, and $f′(\frac{6}{3}) = 1$, which is perpendicular as required. $f(\frac{6}{3}) = 3$, a whole number as required.

Comment: So basicily your saying my derivative wasn't correct ? I thought 1 / (1/3t) == 3t , is it not? and than the derivative of 3t is 3 isn't that so?

Comment: You have $f′(t/3)$ equal to a constant (3.416). It isn't a constant.

Comment: I am still trying to understand why though , isnt 1/ (1/3t) == 3t ?? The derivatives are difference though , so weired.

Comment: Yes $1/(1/(3t)) = 3t$. And derivative of $3t$ is $3$. But that doesn't change the fact that $f'(x)$ (where $x$ is any variable) is still not a constant. So a statement like  $f'(t/3)=3.416$ doesn't make sense. In fact $f'(x)$ is always less than $5/4$ since $1/(x^2)$ is always positive (or positive infinity).

Comment: But here is where I need help , even wolfram alpha , says that the derivative of 5*(t/3) / 4 + 1/ (t / 3) == 5/12 -3/t^2 , than I know I was wrong with my derivative , but can someone help me under stand how @user2460798 got that f'(t/3) = 1.25 - 9/t^2 , I mean your answers check out , but how did you get to that derivative? could you help me here?

Comment: I think I see the problem. There is a difference between $f'(t/3)$ and $(f(t/3))'$. In the first one has $f'(x) = 5/4 - 1/x^2$ then substitute $t/3$ for $x$ which gives $f'(t/3) = 5/4 - 1/(t/3)^2 = 5/4 - 9/t^2$. In the second you have $f(t/3) = 5(t/3)/4 + 3/t$ and then taking derivative of that WRT $t$. Which gives $5/12 - 3/t^2$. I think it is easier to work WRT to $x$, and not introduce $t$. But if you are introducing it, then remember everything becomes WRT $t$, in particular $y(t) = 5t/12+ 3/t$. Also, when you said $f'(t/3) = 5/12 + 3$ you are assuming $t=1$, which isn't true in general.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $a=3b$ and $f'(a)\cdot f'(b)=-1$, where $f'(x)=\frac{5}{4}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}$.

Then, $f'(a)\cdot f'(b)=f'(a)\cdot f'(\frac{1}{3}a)=(\frac{5}{4}-\frac{1}{a^{2}})\cdot (\frac{5}{4}-\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{3}a)^{2}})=\frac{25}{16}-\frac{25}{2a^{2}}+\frac{9}{a^{4}}$

Therefore, $\frac{25}{16}-\frac{25}{2a^{2}}+\frac{9}{a^{4}}=-1$. Solving this equation, you'll find that $a=2$ is the only solution that verifies the hypothesis.

Afterwards, $f(a)=f(2)=\frac{5}{4}\cdot 2+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=3$ and $f(b)=f(\frac{2}{3})=\frac{7}{3}$.

So, you obtain $A(2,3)$ and$B(0.666,2.333)$.